# Common Mistakes Using Breadboard: What's Wrong?

Tags: breadboard, circuits

I didn't wire my circuit correctly and burnt out all my LEDs. I put the resistor's nodes in the same 5 hole row and put each terminal of LED in separate rows. The LED lit up, but soon after blew up. Why can't the resistor or the LED terminals be placed in the same 5 hole row?

Comment: Could you add a schematic?

Comment: In addition to the schematic, can you upload a photo of your breadboard setup?

Comment: LEDs are very easy to burn out, breadboard or no breadboard.

Comment: Gazing into my crystal ball...  most likely either (a) resistors too low value, or (b) you managed to connect the power so as to bypass the resistors and connect straight to the LEDs.

Answer (score 3):

> "Why can't the resistor or the LED terminals be placed in the same 5 hole row?"

Because the "same 5 hole row" are all connected together:

[image: Breadboard Connections]

So if you plug both ends of a resistor into the same 5-hole row, there is a piece of metal shorting the resistor out. Similarly, if you plug both anode and cathode of an LED into the same 5-hole row, you short the LED out.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you set a resistor to limit current to (LED current * 5). But, diodes, including LEDs, don't all act identically. So, one LED will start conducting and basically hog up all the current. It'll start to burn out, and the current will then go to the next one - effectively burning out all your LEDs one at a time.

It's a design best practice to use one resistor per LED.